# \special, html: URLs, and trouble with the pound sign

Tags: urls, arguments, hyperlink, specials

EDIT: [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) has provided the correct answer. Thank you, Ulrike.

I've been given an interesting project involving creating syntax diagrams for a webpage. Because they use things like large braces and eqalign-style presentation, \TeX\ was the obvious choice (I'm using `xetex` for font flexibility). To generate the graphics, I'm using `dvisvgm`, which allows `dvips`-like `\special` commands.

The problem I'm having is with terms, which are words that need to link to anchors in a webpage, and I am going slightly insane with creating URLs with `#` in them.

My latest attempt looks something like this:

```
\nopagenumbers
\font\termfont="Consolas/I" at 10pt
\def\baseurl{https://someplace.org/dir}
\def\doca{\baseurl/doca.html}
\def\docb{\baseurl/docb.html}
\def\pound{\begingroup\catcode`\#=11\relax #\endgroup}
\def\myterm#1#2#3{%
    \hbox{\termfont\special{html:<a href="#1\pound#2">}#3\special{html:</a>}}
}

$$\eqalign{
    \myterm{\doca}{anchor1}{thingy1} &= \hbox{description 1}\cr
    \myterm{\docb}{anchor2}{thingy2} &= \hbox{description 2}\cr
}$$

\bye
```

This, of course, results in an error:

```
(./untitled-3.tex
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pound.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.6 ...{\begingroup\catcode`\#=11\relax #\endgroup
                                                  }
? _
```

But I'm not sure why, because *I just changed the* `\catcode` *to be a letter, dangit*.

Previous attempts have included

```
def\myterm#1#2#3{%
    \hbox{\termfont\special{html:<a href="#1###2">}#3\special{html:</a>}}
}
```

which you'd think would work in this context, but the URL comes out as (say) `http://someplace.org/dir/doca.html##anchor1`, and I don't know why. I've been getting increasingly weird, trying different combinations of `\char"23` (just puts those literal characters in the URL), changing up `\catcode` in various ways, experimenting with various `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` and other combinations thereof, and I'm starting to wonder whether I even \TeX\ or not.

What am I missing here? I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: you are changing the catcode to late. You need something like ``{\catcode`\#=11 \gdef\pound{#}}``

Comment: Ulrike, you have saved my sanity. Thank you.

Comment: Has to be said though that the Unicode symbol POUND SIGN is U+00A3 which is £

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fight with catcodes you can use `\string` which always produces catcode 12 (or catcode 10 space) tokens.

```
a

\def\zz#1#2{\special{html:<a href="#1\string###2">}}
\zz{https://example.com}{foo}

b

\bye
```

Processed with `xetex --no-pdf` then `dviasm` to see the dvi structure shows

```
  push:
    right: 20pt
    fnt: cmr10 at 10pt
    set: 'a'
  pop:
  xxx: 'html:<a href="https://example.com#foo">'
  down: 12pt
  push:
    right: 20pt
    set: 'b'
  pop:
```

with a single `#` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the post acknowledging Ulrike's answer.

In short, Ulrike suggested the following change:

```
{\catcode`\#=11\relax \gdef\pound{#}}
\def\myterm#1#2#3{%
    \hbox{\ttrm \special{html:<a href="#1\pound#2">}#3\special{html:</a>}}
}
```

I had, sadly, completely forgotten about `\gdef`. But this works perfectly and reliably, and I can't thank her enough.